# Reading csv file and ignoring the top row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, pandas-groupby

I have one xlsx file and the data contain like this :

[I have to remove the "Magna" key" fom the below excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYbsg.png)

My code is :

```
data = pd.read_excel("abc.xlsx")
data1 = data.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True) #replace NaN with ""
data1.columns = data1.columns.str.replace('Unnamed.*', '') #Removing unNamed
for j in userInputForRemove: #["magna"]
    if j in allElementInExcel: #["contail all elements in xlsx"]
        pattern = re.compile(r'\b'+j+r'\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        data1 = data1.replace(pattern, "", regex=True)
data1.to_excel(i, index=False)
```

But after delete "magna" keyWord, i am getting below input.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQPEq.png)

But i want to delete all "magna" keyword. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Have you tried the `skiprows` argument of `read_csv`?

Comment: Its not working @GiladGreen. I have tried

Comment: Please add the attempt using this argument

Comment: i edited the question. Can you please look into this and provide me solution.

Comment: Your title says “reading CSV” and your code says `read_excel`. Excel is not CSV. Your comment says you “have tried” `skiprows` and your code does not show that. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`skiprows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
data = pd.read_csv('path-to-csv.csv', skiprows=1)
```